# isolated storage windows phone rewrite

Tags: c#

I have a problem when I try to rewrite in the isolated storage already created the program send me an error. I hope you guys can help me.

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if(isf.FileExists("PlanoAlimentar"))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("PlanoAlimentar", FileMode.Open, isf));
                        sw.Write(Titulo + ";" + PA + "-" + MDM + "-" + A + "-" + MT + "-" + J + "/");
                        sw.Close();
}
else
{
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("PlanoAlimentar", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf));
                        sw.Write(Titulo + ";" + PA + "-" + MDM + "-" + A + "-" + MT + "-" + J + "/");
   sw.Close();

}
```

Comment: It might help if you actually told us what kind of error you're getting ;)

Comment: System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: Its ok now just need to close de sr.read